# startActivity() doesn't display new activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'am new to android , so please bear with me.
I'am trying to display another activity after a timer of 5 seconds, but it doesn't show up. I've made sure both the activities are in the manifest file.

`Splash.java` :

```
package com.example.pournima.metallica;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class Splash extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run() {

        try{
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }catch(Exception e){

        }finally{
            Intent in = new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }


        }
    };

}
}
```

`MainActivity.java` :

```
package com.example.pournima.metallica;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

`AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.pournima.metallica" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.pournima.TheStart" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: I think You forgot to start thread

Comment: Also using handler is much better choice than a thread with sleep and i guess its a splash scree which itself not a good idea. You can have a branded launch now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `timer.start()`

Once you create a thread , you need to start it too ^^

```
public void run() {

    try{
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }catch(Exception e){

    }finally{
        Intent in = new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }


    }
};

timer.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

Add  `timer.start();`  as

```
Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run() {

        try{
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }catch(Exception e){

        }finally{
            Intent in = new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }


        }
    };

timer.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create handler as well instead thread as follows,and make sure you have to finish splash activity as it is splash screen

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // Start your app main activity
                Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

remove timer thread and add this code

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                            startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class));
                        }
                    }
                }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot to start the thread. So just call `timer.start();`

Add below code to your Splash.java class.

```
Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run() {

        try{
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }catch(Exception e){

        }finally{
            Intent in = new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }


        }
    };
timer.start();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

in splash Activity class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    getSplash();
}
```

In getSplash() method :

```
private void getSplash() {


    Handler welcome_handler = new Handler();

    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(Constants.SPALASH_TIMMING);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                finish();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
```